# Download Sun Studio via CLI

Tags: solaris, ubuntu-10.04, wget

Can anybody please guide me how to download the sun studio from CLI. I was using wget and lynx programs but not worked. As I have only SSH access to my server and I cant not download it on local machine and upload it on server, will be bad option for me as it will take hours to upload.

Sun Studio download requires registration + authentication. I have both but not sure how to include those options while downloading via CLI.

Comment: Suggestion - Edit your question with an explanation of why Lynx didn't work, or this will probably get closed as "too localized" or "not a real question."

Comment: My actual question is how to download the sun studio using lynx or wget tools. As I have only ssh access to server.

Comment: Explain why Lynx didn't work when you tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SSH access, you probably have SFTP access as well. Try downloading it locally and uploading it to your server with SFTP. They both run on port 22, SFTP is actually part of the SSH suite.

Edit - so what happens when you put this URL (for Oracle Solaris Studio 12.2 for Solaris 10 OS
on SPARC) into Lynx? http://download.oracle.com/otn/solaris/studio/SolarisStudio12.2-solaris-sparc-pkg-ML.tar.bz2

When I do it, I get prompted for > Username for 'Single Sign-On' at server 'login.oracle.com:443':

which is the same thing I get if I do it from a GUI browser. Since I don't have an Oracle login, I can't test this any further for you. If you have problems after this point, maybe you should contact the vendor?

Comment: Thats not the option i can use here because of my Internet speed..

Answer (score 1):

If your workstation has an X server you could always `ssh -X host` and then run `firefox`. Not a great answer but it does work for most things.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried downloading in lynx it is actually working if you give username and password with the link http://download.oracle.com/otn/solaris/studio/SolarisStudio12.2-solaris-sparc-pkg-ML.tar.bz2

Comment: I tried it, and its giving me "Bad Request"